# R Data wrangling

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I am new to R, I have a csv file that contains values:

```
A, , ,
,B, ,
, ,C1,
, , ,D1
, , ,D2
, ,C2,
, , ,D3
, , ,D4
```

Loading the data into a data frame:

```
dat = read.csv("~/RData/test.csv", header = FALSE)
dat
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  A         
# 2     B      
# 3       C1   
# 4          D1
# 5          D2
# 6       C2   
# 7          D3
# 8          D4
```

I need to wrangle this to a data frame format:

```
A,B,C1,D1
A,B,C1,D2
A,B,C2,D3
A,B,C2,D4
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post the result of `dput(dat)`?

Comment: Looks like you could do a Last Observation Carried Forward/backward [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2776135/903061) and then remove duplicates, [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13967063/903061).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push up and tighten Dataframe. General solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490524/push-up-and-tighten-dataframe-general-solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. This solution follows the link in Gregor's comments. But instead of using `zoo` package, here I show the use of `fill` function from `tidyr`, `na.omit` from base R, and `distinct` function from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = "down") %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  distinct(V4, .keep_all = TRUE)
dt2
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  A  B C1 D1
2  A  B C1 D2
3  A  B C2 D3
4  A  B C2 D4
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "V1 V2 V3 V4
1  A NA NA NA         
                 2  NA  B NA NA      
                 3  NA  NA  C1 NA   
                 4  NA  NA  NA D1
                 5  NA  NA  NA D2
                 6  NA  NA  C2 NA   
                 7  NA  NA  NA D3
                 8  NA  NA  NA D4",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks allot, this is elegant I used this as basis.

Answer (score 2):

By using `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
df[df==' '] <- NA
df[1:3] <- lapply(df[1:3], na.locf0, fromLast = FALSE)
df <- df[!is.na(df$V4),]
df
```

giving:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
4  A  B C1 D1
5  A  B C1 D2
7  A  B C2 D3
8  A  B C2 D4
```

or by using magrittr too we can write the above code in terms of this pipeline:

```
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)

df %>% 
   replace(. == ' ', NA) %>%
   replace(1:3, lapply(.[1:3], na.locf0, fromLast = FALSE)) %>%     
   subset(!is.na(V4))
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck feel free to modify it ;-)