# Merge rows (with character data) that may or may not be the same individual

Tags: r, merge, character

So I have two datasets with one having a value ID and say variables a,b and c; the other ones alo has IDs but with variables c,d,e. These two datasets have individuals in common but not all of them. I tried a dyplr::left join but it removes the rows from the second datset that do not match the ones in the first.
So I just created and ordered columns in both datasets so that I can just do a rbind. Problem is I now have somethhing like this (example with made up data):

```
  index  b  c  d
1     A  B  A  A
2     B NA  C  D
3     B  B NA NA
4     C  D  E  C
5     D  D  D  D
6     E NA  E NA
7     E NA NA  F
8     E  G NA NA
9     F  F  F  F
```

and I would like to have:

```
  index  b  c  d
1     A  B  A  A
2     B  B  C  D
3     C  D  E  C
4     D  D  D  D
5     E  G  E  F
6     F  F  F  F
```

Apparently, a similar question has been asked in [Push up and tighten Dataframe. General solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490524/push-up-and-tighten-dataframe-general-solution), but it was wih numbers, the sum function does not work in my case. I have tried adapting it replacing by paste and paste0 but it does not work. 
I also tried the second solution in this [Merge rows in one data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285663/merge-rows-in-one-data-frame?rq=1) (setDT+ lapply) it works for the example but I have "Error in eval(bysub, x, parent.frame()) : object 'A' not found" in the true dataset.

The solution as `df1 %>% group_by(index) %>% summarise_all(na.omit)` with dplyr proposed in the first comment also works in the example but not on true data because of the error: "Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Column Nom must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2" with "Nom" being the first column after the index made of strings of several words with spaces and punctuation. Doing `length(Nom)` outputs the number of lines.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(index) %>% summarise_all(na.omit)`

Comment: Thanks for this answer.It works on the example but when I try to apply it to my true data I get "Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Nom` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2" with `Nom`being the name of my first column after the index column.

Comment: Although this question does not appear to be a duplicate, it is still an incomplete question. Please make sure you provide enough information/data/code to fully reproduce the (incorrect) output that you included in the question.

Comment: I can't really share the data as it is private :/, I'm ivestigating further the details of what's happening with the length of my columns and will edit for any update.

Comment: `df1<-aggregate.data.frame(df,list(index), function(x) paste(x[!is.na(x)]))
df1$index<-NULL
df1` . By doing that I got something working in both datasets, I think the problem comes from that I have indexes for which the same column is filled both times which creates vectors in the merged column, that would explain why the dplyr doesn't work. It's progress I just have to find a way to transform a vector with 2 vales into a unique one now.